# Does Alfresco provide html/js components to integrate in web app?

Tags: javascript, html, api, alfresco

Is there an html/js plugin for Alfresco which you can integrate in your web app making it possible for the user to manage a photo, or do you need to use the REST or CMIS APIs? See the following web app example showing what I would like to achieve.

[image: UI mock-up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is not embedded or out-of-the-box html/js framework to do so, but you can easily create a webscript in freemarker template (it's basically an html page with inline access to alfresco javascript root objects). you can there inject jQuery, bootstrap, kendoUI, or anything you like in order to create a fresh and custom UI with access to Alfresco content. You don't have to use neither REST or CMIS APIs in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: I hadn't heard of freemarker templates before. Where should I read more about it? In http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Template_Guide ?

Comment: This is where you should start looking:
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/FreeMarker_Template_Cookbook